# How to refer to recent messages of "Getting Lock" when commiting

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When committing, is it possible to refer to recent messages of locking files?
Only commit messages are shown by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it looks like the lock comments are not getting cached as recent commit log messages do.